# How to execute PostgreSQL function at specific time interval?

Tags: postgresql

Is there anything similar to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) [`setTimeInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) in PostgreSQL which allows to execute piece of code (`FUNCTION`) at specified time interval?

As far as I know only thing that can execute a `FUNCTION` according to certain event is [Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) but it is not time based but operation driven (`INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE / TRUNCATE`)

While I could do this in application code, but prefer to have it delegated to database. Anyway I could achieve this in PostgreSQL? May be an extension?

Comment: [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/) or [pg_timetable](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_timetable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. It's called `pg_sleep`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        PERFORM pg_sleep(1);
        RAISE NOTICE 'This is a notice!';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT my_function();
```

This will raise the notice every second. You can also make it do other things instead of raising a notice.

*OR*

You can use PostgreSQL's [Background Worker](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bgworker.html#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20can%20be%20extended%20to,linked%20to%20the%20server%27s%20status.) feature.

The following is a simple example of a background worker that prints a message every 5 seconds:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION print_message() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Hello, world!';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schedule_print_message() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  job_id BIGINT;
BEGIN
  SELECT bgw_start_recurring_job(
    'print-message',
    'print_message',
    '5 seconds'
  ) INTO job_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT schedule_print_message();
```

Comment: Thanks mate, actually what I wanted was something similar to `setTimeInterval`, I mess things up a bit, since your answer address both cases, I edited the question on include `setTimeInterval` too.